# Appending/overriding .conf files in Yocto build system

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I have a distro layer "meta-clayer" from a 3rd party which i do not want to edit.

Is there any method in yocto to append/overwrite some settings in distro.conf in "meta-clayer" by appending it from my custom created layer similar to bbappend method.

Any inputs will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own layer "meta-my-layer", inside

> meta-my-layer/conf/layer.conf

set

```
LAYERDEPENDS_meta-my-layer = "clayer"

BBFILE_PRIORITY_meta-my-layer = "100" 
#Could be any number higher than the one in meta-clayer/conf/layer.conf
```

create your own distro in conf/distro/include/mydistro.conf
copy paste the distro of meta-clayer inside it and do your own modification.
Do not forget to update your DISTRO variable in conf/local.conf.

An other way would be to override "settings" in your local.conf file which is the file with the higher priority but this is really not advised and not the best practice.

Comment: Does the instruction LAYERDEPENDS_meta-my-layer = "clayer" cause the contents in the meta-clayer/conf/distro/distro.conf to be overwritten with contents of distro.conf in meta-my-layer. Will this work for appending also.

Comment: Is it necessary to copy the entire contents from meta-clayer/conf/distro.conf to meta-my-layer/conf/distro/mydistro.conf. Will copying only those settings which needs to be changed not sufficient?